# Is it possible to "hijack" and delay document ready event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm embedding an iframe, which is a simple website that contains some Javascript. The JS has a few `$(document).ready` handlers.

The problem is, they fire when the iframe's load event triggers, which happens after I set the `src` attribute & all the resources have been loaded. However, I have some work I need to do before that - namely, compiling a Handlebars template for the main `body` tag.

So, ideally I'd like to:

- set the `src` attribute
- grab the Handlebars template
- once the resources are loaded, render the template and set the `html` of the `body` tag
- execute all `doc.ready` handlers from the original iframe's Javascript

Is this possible? I'd need to get all the handlers, and then manually trigger the `load` event on the iframe's body once I append the rendered template. But my attempts

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').trigger('load')
```

aren't working. Any tips?

Comment: looks like jQuery has this thing [.holdReady()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/) for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`$.holdReady()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/), like so:

```
$.holdReady(true);

// do stuff

$.holdReady(false); // execute all pending .ready callbacks
```

I haven't tried it with an iframe, but should work.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this for non-jQuery code? i.e. handlers that subscribe directly to window load event?

Comment: How about saving `window.onload` to another variable, emptying it, and reusing that variable when you're ready?